# How do I retrieve locally stored sql file and parse it in json data format to an external url in QML?

Tags: javascript, c++, sqlite, qml, qt5

I'm developing a desktop app in QML and want to make the inserted data locally available when the client PC is offline but sync with an external server upon internet connectivity.

In Qt 5.9.1, I did import the qt localStorage module and I was able to insert the data and store it locally in /.local/share/XXXXX/QML/OfflineStorage/Databases

```
//main.qml file
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0


ApplicationWindow {
    id: rootWindow
    visible: true
    width: 1000
    height: 800
    title: qsTr("Hello World!")

function user userDataBase()
{
    var db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("UserInfoApp", "1.0", "Storage example!", 1000000);
    try {
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserDetails(firstname TEXT, secondname TEXT, date_of_birth TEXT)');
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error creating table in database: " + err)
    };
    return db;
}
// Insert New user
function dbInsert(firstname, secondname, date_of_birth) 
{
    var dbInsert()
    var rowid = 0;
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO UserDetails VALUES(?, ?, ?)', [firstname, secondname, date_of_birth]);
        rowid = result.insertId
    })
    return rowid;
}

GridLayout {
    columns:3
    TextField {
       id: firstname
       placeholderText: qsTr("First Name")
   }
   TextField {
       id: secondname
       placeholderText: qsTr("Second Name")
   }
   TextField {
       id: date_of_birth
       placeholderText: qsTr("Date of Birth")
   }
}

    Button {
        text: qsTr("Save User")
        onClicked: dbInsert(firstname.text, secondname.text, date_of_birth.text)
    }
}
```

I expect to post the locally available data in json format to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000/students/faculty/engineering/ upon internet connectivity of the client PC or to manually prompt the client PC to sync with the online server.

Comment: So what is your question? What exactly are you having trouble with? Querying database? Preparing JSON? Sending the data to a remote host? And how your code you've provided can help/explain the issue?

Comment: @folibis I need a guideline (or maybe a link to resources that might be of help) on checking net connectivity logic of which I believe Qt has a role here, also need to read all the values from db, make json format data and send them to my remote server. The piece of code above doesn't explain much but my efforts so far.

Comment: [executeSql](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-localstorage-qmlmodule.html#results-tx-executesql-statement-values) to select data from the database, [XMLHttpRequest](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-qmlglobalobject.html#xmlhttprequest) to send a data to a remote server. Making JSON is just a string concatenation I guess here shouldn't be a problem.